# Vim: use NERDTree cursorline without affecting cursorline in other windows?

Tags: vim

I'd like to make my NERD_Tree windows easier to read, and the `'NERDTreeHighlightCursorline'` option makes it easy to do so. Except I currently have a setup I like that allows me to highlight the cursorline-number without highlighting the whole line:

```
set cursorline                " turn on cursorline
highlight clear CursorLine    " highlight line-number only
```

Though the `'cursorline'` option is local to each window, the highlighting is global. The only way I can figure out to work around this is adding some autocommands to add/clear a highlight when I enter/leave the NERDTree window:

```
augroup NerdCursor
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter NERD_tree_* hi CursorLine gui=underline
  autocmd BufLeave NERD_tree_* highlight clear CursorLine
  autocmd BufAdd * highlight clear CursorLine
augroup END
```

The underline shows up in all windows, but I can live with it if it's the only way. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `:highlight` definitions are global, and you cannot use another highlight group without emulating the *cursorline* functionality yourself, I don't see any more elegant solution. Your set of `:autocmd`s is how I would work around the problem, too.